# Is Cocos2d-x commercial quality?

Tags: game-engine, libgdx, cocos2d-x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cocos2D OR libgdx for Android Game Developement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552176/cocos2d-or-libgdx-for-android-game-developement)

I am interested in using cocos2d-x for Android and iOS development but not sure it its ready for prime time? How does cocos2d-x compare to libgdx on android?  It seems like they could spend some more time on documentation, and feature updates is slow right now.   On the other hand LibGDX seems to have issues ... I think Cocos2d-x is more idealistic running on iOS and Android.  A major C++ +.

Where are the apps developed using Cocos2d-x?

Comment: Define "commercial quality" ...

Comment: Like you can make a successful commerical game with it.

Comment: At the time this post was made there were already successful commercial games available that were made with Cocos2d-x.  Hero academy being one of note.

Comment: Dragon City was coded with 2dx too

Comment: I know this is old, but I need to make a point: download the quake 3 source code. It's a giant filthy buggy hack, and yet John Carmack is a millionaire with coding awards out the wazoo. Just make your game, forget the code quality critics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't really agree with your statement about "feature updates is slow right now". The cocos2d-x project is evolving and they've released version 2.0.1 less than a month ago. They're also targeting new platforms (win8, win phone) and new technologies (like Javascript).

I agree that the documentation is not great, but most cocos2d documentation is useful for cocos2d-x as they're targeting feature parity with it. Also, let me suggest you a tutorial that explains really well how to setup cocos2d-x on both iOS and Android:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started (part 1)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/11338/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-space-game (part 2)

There's also a free, online Cocos2d-X book being written:

http://wizardfu.com/book/cocos2d-x/

Comment: Those tutorials are a great improvement.  Win8 is going to be very important.  I agree with the principal that C++ is the most fast and portal approach.  You can leverage more libraries this way.

Comment: I do think some an important questions remain like importing resources from blender, doing animations etc.  I would expect to see these things a little farther along.

Comment: Also how does Cocos2dx compare with libGDX as far as Box2d integration?

Comment: I think another major concern here is tool support. I mean on windows you cannot really do everything in visual c++. So it looks like tool support and documentation are somewhat behind.

Comment: Box2d - perfect integration. Regarding tool support, you now have Cocos2DBuilder, which is also supported in cocos2d-x 2.0, and a set of tools called LevelHelper/SpriteHelper, which provide a WYSWIG approach, including box2d physics. Anyway, I went down the Cocos2d-x path because as long as you have an active community and a real well thought out API you just can't go wrong (IMHO).

Comment: Regarding Blender you're not in much luck. Although cocos2d-x uses OpenGL at its core, its mainly 2D. There's no such thing as support for 3d models, animations, etc. There's a project in the Cocos2d space called cocos3D that adds support for 3d, but it hasn't been migrated to Cocos2d-x.